# How to create functions for select on javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]

To be more specific' I added a photo. I need to create a select box so when I choose a title, the img below will change.

I know how to create everything, but I don't understand which action function (I forgot the name- similar to 'onchange' and 'onmouseover') I need to type in order for it to work. Heres my code so far:

[MMy code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhCx5.png)

Comment: Post the actual code, rather than a link to it, please.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/ref_eventattributes.asp).

Answer (score 1):

onchange is for any input changing.
In the case of select, just changing the option will trigger, but with text inputs you need to lose the focus of the input too.

If you want the action to happen at the button click instead of the change of the input field, then use onclick to trigger your custom js function to do the work on the image.

Comment: In the case of a `<select>`, it doesn't have to lose focus. `onchange` runs as soon as you change the menu.

Comment: true Barmar, i'll clarify it